# sequelize query findAll using multiple constraints in where arg

Tags: javascript, express, sequelize.js

New to sequelize here!

looking for a way to use 2 arguments from res.query.

without any request.query works OK.

hardcoded all works OK.

with only phone also works OK.

Any way to use both of them at same time (doing AND or OR) between them?

or.... any way to check all var in res.query and apply them as required!?

regards

```
exports.findAll = (req, res, next) => {
  const { phone, active } = req.query;  // phone(string), active(boolean)

  let condPhone = phone ? { userPhone: { [Op.like]: `%${phone}%` } } : null;
  let condActive = active ? { userActive: Boolean(active) } : null;

  Saloia.Users.findAll({ where: condActive })
    .then((data) => res.send(data))
    .catch((err) => {
      err.status = 500;
      next(err);
    });
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put multiple conditions as an object for the value of `where`.

```
Saloia.Users.findAll({
  where: {
      foo: bar,
      foo2: bar2
    }
});
```

Comment: yes literals works just fine! how about a function call in the where body?

Answer (score 0):

I think I solved the situation

```
exports.findAll = (req, res, next) => {

  const { phone, active, last } = req.query;
  let options = { where: {} };

  // string
  phone ? (options.where.userPhone = { [Op.like]: `%${phone}%` }) : null;
  // boolean
  active ? (options.where.userActive = tmp = active === "true") : null;
  // date/time
  last ? (options.where.userLstMsg = {[Op.gt]: moment().subtract(last, 'hours').toDate()}) : null; 

  Saloia.Users.findAll(options)
    .then((data) => res.send(data))
    .catch((err) => {
      err.status = 500;
      next(err);
    });
};
```

in this case I could use like those

http://mydomain/api/users?phone=351XXXXXXXXX     // any number or part

http://mydomain/api/users?active=true&last=24 // active user logged in the last 24h

and here the json file for reference

```
{
    "userLstMsg": "2020-04-08T05:48:49.910Z",
    "userId": "U.k8qwwlmh",
    "userPhone": "351123456789",
    "userName": "my user",
    "userActive": true
}
```